# Google sheet: Export range as PDF and save it in a specific sub folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using the script [here](https://xfanatical.com/blog/print-google-sheet-as-pdf-using-apps-script/) on exporting my sheet as a PDF. I just want to know if how can I save the pdf file in a specific sub folder.

Here's the image of the directory:

[image]

Note the under the ARCS folder, there are files and folders with grade level that has the same files like the one in the picture above.

Here's the modified code that I'm currently working on.

```js
function _exportBlob(blob, fileName) {
  
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "yyyy");
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  var fileName = "FORM137 - " + ss.getRange("REPORT CARD!D12").getValue() + " - ARCS" + date;
  var ssID = ss.getId();
  var ssFile = DriveApp.getFileById(ssID);
 
  blob = blob.setName(fileName)

  var subFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("CARDS").next();
  var pdfFile = subFolder.createFile(blob)

  const htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<p>Click to open <a href="' + pdfFile.getUrl() + '" target="_blank">' + fileName + '</a></p>')
    .setWidth(300)
    .setHeight(80)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Export Successful')
}
```

```js
function exportNamedRangesAsPDF() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var allNamedRanges = spreadsheet.getNamedRanges()
  var toPrintNamedRanges = []
  for (var i = 0; i < allNamedRanges.length; i++) {
    var namedRange = allNamedRanges[i]
    if (/^print_area_.*$/.test(namedRange.getName())) {
      Logger.log('found named range ' + namedRange.getName())
      toPrintNamedRanges.push(namedRange.getRange())
    }
  }
  if (toPrintNamedRanges.length === 0) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('No print areas found. Please add at least one \'print_area_1\' named range in the menu Data > Named ranges.')
    return
  } else {
    toPrintNamedRanges.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.getSheet().getIndex() - b.getSheet().getIndex()
    })
    exportPartAsPDF(toPrintNamedRanges)
  }
}
```

Exporting is working, but the files are currently saving in CARDS in Grade 2 folder while I'm working on the Grade 1 folder. It should be in Grade 1 folder and not Grade 2.

I think that this code should be the one to modify.

`var subFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("CARDS").next();`

I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to create a file to the subfolder of `CARDS` in the folder of `Grade 1`.

In your situation, I thought that there might be several folders with the folder name of `CARDS`. In this case, I think that it is required to check the parent folder of each folder retrieved by `DriveApp.getFoldersByName("CARDS")`. So, for this, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var subFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("CARDS").next();
var pdfFile = subFolder.createFile(blob)

const htmlOutput = HtmlService
  .createHtmlOutput('<p>Click to open <a href="' + pdfFile.getUrl() + '" target="_blank">' + fileName + '</a></p>')
  .setWidth(300)
  .setHeight(80)
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Export Successful')
```

#### To:

```
var parentFolderName = "Grade 1";
var pdfFile;
var subFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("CARDS");
while (subFolder.hasNext()) {
  var f = subFolder.next();
  if (f.getParents().next().getName() == parentFolderName) {
    pdfFile = f.createFile(blob);
  }
}
if (pdfFile) {
  const htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<p>Click to open <a href="' + pdfFile.getUrl() + '" target="_blank">' + fileName + '</a></p>')
    .setWidth(300)
    .setHeight(80)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Export Successful')
}
```

or

#### From:

```
var subFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("CARDS").next();
var pdfFile = subFolder.createFile(blob)
```

#### To:

```
var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Grade 1").next();
var subFolder = parentFolder.getFoldersByName("CARDS").next();
var pdfFile = subFolder.createFile(blob);
```

- In this modified script, the folder of `CARDS` in the folder of `Grade 1` is used. And `blob` is created to the folder as a file.
- In this modification, `Grade 1` is used as the parent folder name. But if your actual folder name is not `Grade 1`, please modify it.
- At 2nd pattern, it supposes that there is only one folder of `Grade 1` and there is only one folder of `CARDS` in the folder of `Grade 1`. Please be careful this.

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that there is only one folder of the folder name of `CARDS` in the folder of `Grade 1`. If there are several folders with the same folder name of `CARDS` in the folder of `Grade 1`, it is required to check them. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [getFoldersByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfoldersbynamename)
- [Class FolderIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator)
- [getParents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getparents)

### Added:

If the folder `Grade 1` is the parent folder of `var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` in your below script, I think that above pattern 2 can be modified as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId()).getParents().next();
var subFolder = parentFolder.getFoldersByName("CARDS").next();
var pdfFile = subFolder.createFile(blob);
```

Comment: Is there no other way for it to just get the parent folder and not modify it one by one?

Comment: @cjvdg Thank you for replying. About your replying, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? In that case, it supposes that there is only one folder name of `Grade 1` and `Grade 2` in your Google Drive. Please be careful this.

Comment: The second one works for me. But is there no other way for me to not type or declare the `Grade 1` in a variable?

Comment: @cjvdg Thank you for replying. I apologize that my proposal was not useful for your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. At first, can I ask you about whether my understanding of your situation is correct? In your situation, I thought that there might be several folders with the folder name of `CARDS`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. It is correct and that's okay, since your solution works for me. I just want to know if there is a way for me to not change the `Grade 1` variable to Grade 2, 3 or 4 whenever I will use the codes on different sheet? Is there a way for me to automatically get the parent folder name and not declare what folder is it in the code?

Comment: @cjvdg In the case that there are several folders with the same folder name of `CARDS` and you want to put a file to one of the folders of `CARDS`, it is required to check the parent folder of each folder of `CARDS`. So when you want to put the file using the folder name, it is required to use the folder names of `Grade 1` and `CARDS`. But if you can put the file using the folder ID, you can directly use the folder like `var pdfFile = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(blob)`. Because at Google Drive, the folders are managed by the folder IDs. How about this?

Comment: @cjvdg Can I ask you about your situation? I understood that in your situation, you want to put the file to `CARDS` in the folder `Grade 1`. In this case, the folder `Grade 1` is the parent folder of `var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`? If it's so, I think that this can be used. By this, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I just don't want to modify or edit the grade one by one so if there is a code that can be used to get the parent folder without declaring the folder name, that is much better.